# Flutter firebase stream has data but returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause, stream-builder

I have a Problem there are some documents in Firestore that have the same location and the location gets passed correctly as it prints out the right string, but my StreamBuilder always executes the noData function in the if condition.

The Streambuilder looks like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FilterFirebase().relatedLocationFilter(
                          eventDocument["location"], eventDocument["id"]),
                      builder: (BuildContext ctx,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                            snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return NoDataRelatedLocation();
                        } else {
                          return new RelatedLocationListing(
                            relatedLocationList: snapshot.data.docs,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    )
```

My relatedLocationFilter looks like this:

```
relatedLocationFilter(String location, String id) {
print(location);
print(id);
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("events")
    .where("location", isEqualTo: location)
    .where("id", isNotEqualTo: id)
    .snapshots();
}
```

The security rules are normal and the code without the where filters is working fine.

Update:

Logs:

flutter: Tj4EB68R1CwBYKPfWzcm

flutter: MGM Banquet Hall

flutter: 1

Firestore Docs:

[image: First Document]

[image: Second Dcoument]

[image: Third Document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct desired result. So though your `stream` returns the proper value, the stream builder first gets null before your `stream` gets data.
So if you don't want to show `NoDataRelatedLocation` before your `stream` gets real data, you should put `initialData` param of your stream builder.

Comment: Hello, this makes sense because when I press hot reload it shows data for a short second. What would I pass as initalData?

Comment: You can pass just `[]`

Comment: Thank you for the help but when doing that I get the following error: the argument type 'StatelessWidget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>)'

Comment: Is that the right way to pass [ ]: initialData: [ ],

Comment: In that case, you need to modify your `relatedLocationFilter` function not to return `QuerySnapshot` but to return array as the result from map of `QuerySnapshot`, and use `AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>`, not `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>`.